# Laravel storage issue while pushing to production server

Tags: laravel-5, gitlab

I am facing permission denied for storage directory everytime when I push to production even its added in gitignore file like:/storage/*
Also I get "can not create public/storage" error and in this case I delete public/storage and again run php artisan storage:link command.

I tried git -r --cached public/storage command to resolve this issue but not resolved.

can anyone suggest a permanent solution for it? I am getting frustrated doing the same thing again and again. And I know I am doing the small mistake that I could not figure out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give read/write permission to your folder

Try this to give it the permission

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage
```

Comment: after given permissions did you check permissions has been changed? @bhattraideb

Comment: Yes, It's being changed. I also changed the ownership but no luck.